# R use apply when arguments contain arrays and scalars

Tags: r, apply

I want to **avoid** the following **loop**:

```
for(i in 1:2){
vectVal[i] = myFunc(M[,,i],S[,,i],phi2, sig2)
}
```

by **using** the **apply** function.

The problem is that the **arguments** passed to the apply function contain **arrays** (--> M and S) and **scalars** (--> phi2 and sig2).

I tried the following:

```
apply(M,3,myFunc, S = S, phi2 = phi2, sig2 = sig2)
```

which resulted in an error message because S is an array and not a matrix as required in myFunc (see below):

Here is a **reproducible code:**

```
M = array(data = c(
  0.5, 0.7, 0.45,
  0.5, 0.3, 0.45,
  0.5, 0.7, 0.3,
  0.5, 0.3, 0.7,
  0.5, 0.7, 0.45,
  0.5, 0.3, 0.55),
  dim = c(3,2,2),
)

S = array(data = c(
   0.7723229, -0.2149794, -0.2159068,
  -0.2149794,  0.7723229, -0.2083123,
  -0.2159068, -0.2083123,  0.7723229,
   0.7723229, -0.2149794, -0.2149794,
  -0.2149794,  0.7723229, -0.1783025,
  -0.2149794, -0.1783025,  0.7723229,
   0.7723229, -0.2149794, -0.2176665,
  -0.2149794,  0.7723229, -0.2111496,
  -0.2176665, -0.2111496,  0.7723229),
   dim = c(3,3,2)
)

phi2 = 0.5
sig2 = 0.3

myFunc = function(M, S, phi2, sig2){
  valMult = M[,1]%*%diag(S)
  valEnd = valMult + phi2 - sig2
return(valEnd)
}

vectVal = vector(length = 2)

for(i in 1:2){
  vectVal[i] = myFunc(M[,,i],S[,,i],phi2, sig2)
}

vectVal
```

Does someone has an idea?

Comment: +1 for a example data and code, but this runs without error for me. Perhaps try it again in a clean R session.

Comment: @Thomas it runs ok, they want an alternative to the `for` loop. Perhaps off-topic and belongs on code review. Also, `S` has 6 elements in the 3rd dimension. Do you really only want to use the first 2?

Comment: @ Thomas: exactly, the for loop works, but not the apply-version

Comment: The exact equivalent of your for loop with *apply would be `sapply(1:2,function(x)myFunc(M[,,x],S[,,x],phi2,sig2))` but I don't really see the improvement.

Comment: @SimonO101: My mistake, the 3rd dimension should have only 2 elements (I corrected the code).

Comment: @plannapus: Since the 3rd dimension of M and S in the original code is much bigger than 2, I thought the apply-version would require less time

Comment: @user3118627 I'm not so sure. You can try benchmarking say the `mapply` answer I give below but I am not sure it will be faster than a vanilla for loop. Try it.

Comment: @user3118627 Take a look at this one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2275896/is-rs-apply-family-more-than-syntactic-sugar

Answer (score 3):

One (not particularly efficient) way would be to use `plyr` to split your arrays into `lists` (each element of the lists are the third dimension of your arrays). You could then use `mapply` to run your function like so:

```
require( plyr)
ml <- alply( M , 3 )
sl <- alply( S , 3 )
mapply( myFunc , ml , sl , phi2 , sig2 )
#       1        2 
#1.474333 1.358484
```

#### Update:

A more vectorised alternative (but still not as fast as `for` and `%*%` [see @JorisMeys comment below]) is to get the `diag` of `S` and then use `colSums` and matrix multiplication like so to achieve the same result:

```
s <- apply(S,3,diag)
colSums( M[,1,] * s ) + phi2 - sig2
# [1] 1.474333 1.358484
```

#### Update, update:

**@JorisMeys** has written a vectorised extractor function for getting the diagonal elements of 3D square arrays. [**Check this out**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7979476/1478381).

Comment: This is about 90 times slower than the for-loop. Although very useful, plyr is not the best choice when performance is an issue.

Comment: mostly plyr, but mapply doesn't offer a speedup compared to the loop either.

Comment: Take a look at the `rbenchmark` package. That will tell you that the loop in the question outperforms the rest, for the simple reason that it's rather impossible to beat `%*%`. OP will have to look at eg Rcpp if he wants a speedup.

Comment: @JorisMeys yeah, I was being lazy not checking. Oh darn.